# Evaluate $\lfloor n / \lfloor n / \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor \rfloor \rfloor$ for positive integers $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm considering:

$$
\left\lfloor {n \over \lfloor n / \lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor\rfloor} \right\rfloor \:\:\:\: \forall n \in \mathbf N^+
$$

which seems to be $\lfloor \sqrt n \rfloor$.

Is there any way to prove or disprove?

Comment: I verified it up to $n=1000$ graphically. Suppose $n$ is a perfect square. Then it is easy to see that the claim is true (set $n=m^2$, and the result is $m$. In fact, we don't even need the outermost floor in that case, so the answer is always less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$ for all positive integers $n$. That goes a good way towards the affirmative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $n$ be a real number such that $n\geq 1$, and $m:=\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$.  Then, we have
$$m^2\leq n< (m+1)^2=m^2+2m+1\leq m^2+3m\,.$$
Thus,
$$m\leq \frac{n}{m}< m+3\,.$$
Set $k:=\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{m}\right\rfloor$, so that $k\in\{m,m+1,m+2\}$.  If $k=m$, then $m^2\leq n<m(m+1)$.  That is,
$$m\le\frac{n}{k}<m+1\,,\text{ whence }\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=m\,.$$
If $k=m+1$, then $m(m+1)\leq n<m(m+2)$.  Thus,
$$m\leq \frac{n}{k}<\frac{m(m+2)}{m+1}=\frac{(m+1)^2-1}{m+1}<m+1\,,$$
so $\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=m$.  If $k=m+2$, then $m(m+2)\leq n<(m+1)^2$.  Hence,
$$m\leq \frac{n}{k}<m+\frac{1}{m+2}<m+1\,,\text{ making }\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=m\,.$$
In other words,
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}\right\rfloor}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$$
for all real numbers $n\geq 1$.

Comment: No, I did mean $m(m+2)\leq n<(m+1)^2$.  Recall that $m=\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor$, so $n<(m+1)^2$ must hold.